# Strange things about new moon

Tags: astronomy, moon, eclipse

I have some strange and infantile questions about new moon. I want to know how is it possible that the Moon is not visible at night and also at day it is not Sun eclipse?
I will explain the problem in a few images.

[image]
[image]
[image]

With these images, how it is possible that there is not solar eclipse at every new moon? Or is there somewhere on Earth?